# How to calculate sum of repeating elements using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

So I am trying to convert an xml file to xsl
Here I have repeating elements like this

```
 <testsuite name="Sanity" tests="5" failures="1" errors="1" skipped="1"timestamp="2023-07-13T17:00:00"/>
 <testsuite name="Something" tests="6" failures="1" errors="1" skipped="1"timestamp="2023-07-13T17:00:00"/>
```

Here I need to calculate the total number of tests, failures etc.
My xsl file will be like this

```
      <th style="text-align: left">Total</th>
      <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="../testsuite">
        <testsuite> 
            <td> 
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(@tests)"/>
            </td>
        </testsuite>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

According to my xsl its giving me the value 5 and 6, these values are not calculating

Comment: Don't post text as an image, paste it and format it as code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `xsl:for-each` to get a sum of nodes. You can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//testsuite/@tests)"/>
```

Of course, it would be more efficient to have an explicit path - e.g. from the context of the parent element, do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(testsuite/@tests)"/>
```